# How to Use gotoDate with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/Calendar-gotoDate

I have no idea how to use calendar.gotoDate( date ) in vue.js

for example https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/defaultDate to access defaultDate I just add it to and works, gotoDate does not work here.

```js
          <FullCalendar
                :key="calendarRender"
                ref="fullCalendar"
                defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                :header="{
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                  }"
                :plugins="calendarPlugins"
                :weekends="calendarWeekends"
                :events="calendarEvents"
                :selectable="true"
                :selectOverlap="false"
                @eventRender="eventRender"
                :dayRender="dayRender"
                :selectAllow="selectAllow"
                :allDayDefault="false"
                @select="select"
                :showNonCurrentDates="false"
                :fixedWeekCount="false"
                :goToDate="currentDate"
            />
```

Tried using and both didn't work either. Gave error in both cassed that is not a function.

```
this.$refs.fullCalendar.gotoDate(new Date('2020-08-11'));
this.$refs.fullCalendar.calendar.gotoDate(new Date('2020-08-11'));
```

The purpose is that after I save and force it to rerender to show new data it goes back to Jun instead of the current month I am working on.

Comment: Run `console.log(this.$refs.fullCalendar)` and then in the console inspect the content of the object to find where is this `gotoDate` function or property. Also, check your template that you use the proper letter case for the name - either `gotoDate` or `goToDate`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I actually used vue dev tool to see those methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/vue (in the section entitled "Accessing FullCalendar's API") you have to get the calendar API object first before you can call methods on it. There is a specific method `getApi()` which you have to call to do this.

Here is the example mentioned in the documentation:

> To do something like this, you’ll need to get hold of the component’s
> ref (short for “reference”). In the template:
>
> `<FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar" :plugins="calendarPlugins" />`

> Once
> you have the ref, you can get the underlying Calendar object via the
> getApi method:
>
> `let calendarApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()`
>
> `calendarApi.next()`

In your case instead of `next()` you'd be calling

```
calendarApi.goToDate('2020-08-11');
```

(Note there's no need to use `new Date` there either - fullCalendar will [accept an ISO8601 date string](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/date-parsing) automatically.)